# Unable to load theme by specified key: ''?

Tags: magento2.3, theme

I updated to **Magento 2.3.5** and now when I open a product in the backend, I am getting `Unable to load theme by specified key: ''`

I googled it and found solutions where I am supposed to delete entries from core_config_data, but there is no entry with an empty key.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: try this and query your database `delete from core_config_data where path = 'design/theme/theme_id' and value = '<your key>';`

Comment: Like I said, there is no entry in core_config_data ...

Comment: what i don't understand ???